# obtain results of two different tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

Table stock

```
fecha       | tarifa

2017-01-06    500 
2017-01-07    500 
2017-01-08    500
```

Table promotions

```
fecha      |  percent

2017-01-07    0.10
2017-01-08    0.10
2017-01-07    0.15
2017-01-08    0.15
```

and i need to obtain while mysql query this:

```
fecha       | tarifa  | percent

2017-01-06    500      0
2017-01-07    500      0.10
2017-01-08    500      0.10
2017-01-06    500      0
2017-01-07    500      0.15
2017-01-08    500      0.15
```

Thank you!!!

Update

i need that create this array with the result of the query.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fecha] => 2017-01-06
                    [tstandard]=>500
                    [porcentaje] => 0.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fecha] => 2017-01-07
                    [tstandard]=>500
                    [porcentaje] => 0.10
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fecha] => 2017-01-08
                    [tstandard]=>500
                    [porcentaje] => 0.10
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fecha] => 2017-01-06
                    [tstandard]=>500
                    [porcentaje] => 0.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fecha] => 2017-01-07
                    [tstandard]=>500
                    [porcentaje] => 0.15
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fecha] => 2017-01-08
                    [tstandard]=>500
                    [porcentaje] => 0.15

                )
        )
)
```

I have done the array but without the tstandard of each day

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` to join two tables when one of them might not contain rows that match the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left outer join` to get the desired output, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.fecha, s.tarifa, IFNULL(p.percent, 0)
FROM stock s LEFT JOIN promotions p ON s.fecha = p.fecha;
```

Here's the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39bb94/2/0).

**Update**

If you want to restrict the output with dates, you can use the below query:

```
SELECT s.fecha, s.tarifa, IFNULL(p.percent, 0)
FROM stock s LEFT JOIN promotions p ON s.fecha = p.fecha
WHERE s.fecha BETWEEN $checkin AND $checkout;
```

Comment: there is a really good solution, but how can i do if the guest select the dates. the table stock is a table that contain every day of the year. there is a hotel reservation system. the table promotion only contain the days of discount. when i try to use left outer join, and use select .... where fecha >= $checkin and fecha <$checkout, the result is column fecha is ambiguous

Comment: ohhh, you are my god. jeje. ¿Can i ask the last question?. How can i make that obtain one array for promotion, and each one include all days thar are consulted. for example one array that contain three days ( 6, 7, 8, - the day 6, 0.00 percent -, and the other days 0.10 percent), and other array also contain the three days (6,7,8 - the day 6, 0.00 percent, and the other days 0.15 percent). Should y make this with php?

Comment: the las table of my query has the result that i want obtain.