# make a multidimensional array php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I link my last question to explain that i need

[obtain results of two different tables mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905105/obtain-results-of-two-different-tables-mysql/41905118?noredirect=1#comment71003701_41905118)

This is the result of my mysql query.

```
date       | rate  | percent

2017-01-06    500      0
2017-01-07    500      0.10
2017-01-07    500      0.15
```

How can i make this array, i am tring with php but i can´t do this, i can do it with one dimension array, but no a multidimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2017-01-06
                    [rate]=>500
                    [percent] => 0.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2017-01-07
                    [rate]=>500
                    [percent] => 0.10
                )   
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2017-01-06
                    [rate]=>500
                    [percent] => 0.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2017-01-07
                    [rate]=>500
                    [percent] => 0.15
                )

            )
)
```

Comment: Can you add your PHP MySQL query ?

Comment: What's the logic behind this multidimensional array? Also, as @Nenroz mentioned ^, include the *relevant* PHP code as well.

Comment: What does that array represent? How should they be grouped? It's kind of hard to see what you're going for without any explanation. You have three results in the database which should be represented in four items in the array?

Comment: sorry, i link my last question

Comment: The result in that question is _not_ the same as in this question so we _still_ have no idea about your logic behind the above multi dimensional array. And please, copy/paste the actual query you're currently using to this question. Don't ask people to read a whole other question (including comments and answers) just to be able to help you with this one.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of (if I understand the problem) plucking the MAX() and MIN() percent values for each date.  For this, you must use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT s.date, s.rate, MAX(p.percent) AS maxperc, MIN(p.percent) AS minperc
    FROM stock s
    LEFT JOIN promotions p ON s.date = p.date
    WHERE s.date BETWEEN '2017-01-29' AND '2017-01-31'
    GROUP BY s.date,s.rate;
```

...I haven't test that, so it may need some fiddling with.

Then as you loop through your result set, you can declare the two separate subarrays and build your complete array.

```
$array=[];
$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[0][$i]["date"]=$row["date"];
    $array[0][$i]["rate"]=$row["rate"];
    $array[0][$i]["perc"]=$row["minperc"];
    $array[1][$i]["date"]=$row["date"];
    $array[1][$i]["rate"]=$row["rate"];
    $array[1][$i]["perc"]=$row["maxperc"];
    ++$i;
}
```

By this point, I've made too many assumptions about your purpose/usage.
Basically, set zero as the percent default, query for highest and lowest percent for each date-rate pair (if zero, then zero will appear as highest and lowest value). Do whatever you wish with the result set.

Comment: @AngelValdez I have only found this question after answering your more-or-less duplicated question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923911/multidimensional-array-query-mysql .  Reposting the same question on SO is a no-no.  Please take the time to merge your question details into this question (because this question has an upvote) and delete the other question.

Comment: @AngelValdez If my solution solves your problem, please award it the green tick (and possibly an upvote for being helpful).  Otherwise please explain what is still not working.

Comment: Geez, I just checked your profile and you have been asking this same question left, right, sideways, English, and Spanish.  Please, please, please consolidate your questions into one so that SO isn't needlessly bloated.